# Making \big/ scalable

Tags: math-mode, scaling

I would like to have a bigger slash symbol. How can I make it scalable? Minimal example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\modslash}{\big/}

\begin{document}
\(A \modslash B_{{A \modslash B}_{A \modslash B}}\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't build the scaler into the macro. Use something like `\newcommand{\modslash}[1][\big]{#1/}`. The scalers cannot be applied to something that already contain a scaler.

Comment: One could think to use the “big” size for the standard `\modslash` symbol, but, alas, the symbol has a very peculiar placement with respect to the baseline.

Comment: You should also be aware of the fact that `\big` and similar *don't* work well in subscripts and superscripts.

Comment: @egreg actually, I quite like the placement of `\big/` in the standard size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\big` and friends in subscripts and superscripts doesn't really work.

For display and text style you can get a bigger slash that scales with `\big` and friends, but with a limitation: `\modslash` and `\big\modslash` will produce the same size.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\modslashsymbol}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{"0E}{largesymbols}{"2E}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifbBigg@
\pretocmd{\bBigg@}{\bBigg@true}{}{}
\apptocmd{\bBigg@}{\bBigg@false}{}{}
\newrobustcmd{\modslash}{\ifbBigg@\modslashsymbol\else\big/\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\(A / B_{{A / B}_{A / B}}\)

\(A \modslash B_{{A \modslash B}_{A \modslash B}}\)

\(\modslash \big\modslash \Big\modslash \bigg\modslash \Bigg\modslash\)

\end{document}
```

What's this? I define a new scalable math symbol based on the bigger version of `/`, which is located in the `largesymbols` font, due to

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{/}{\mathord}{operators}{"2F}{largesymbols}{"0E}
```

I took the location of the next larger symbol from the information in the `.tfm` file, namely

```
(CHARACTER O 16
   (CHARWD R 0.577779)
   (CHARHT R 0.039999)
   (CHARDP R 1.160013)
   (NEXTLARGER O 56)
   )
```

Octal `16 and `56 are hexadecimal `"0E` and `"2E` respectively.

But, as always, there's a catch. The symbols in the `largesymbols` font have a peculiar placement with respect to the baseline; basically, they hang below it, except for a small height that serves for measurements. So just doing

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\modslash}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{"0E}{largesymbols}{"2E}
```

wouldn't work. Thus I patch the inner macro for `\big` and friends to set a conditional to true at the start and to false at the end, so the definition of `\modslash` can use the information and use `\big/` if the conditional is false (when `\modslash` is not used in the context of `\big` and friends).

I kept in the examples `\modslash` in the subscripts, to show it shouldn't be used.

[image]

If you only want automatic `\big` size, that scales in subscripts and superscripts, then it's “easier”.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\modslash}{\mathord{\text{$\m@th\big/$}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \big/ B_{A \big/ B_{A \big/ B}}$

$A \modslash B_{A \modslash B_{A \modslash B}}$

\end{document}
```

Here `unicode-math` is used (as per comment), but the solution is independent on it.

Note you *can't* apply `\big` and friends to this version of `\modslash`.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure, what the conclusion of your answer is. Are you saying that it is not possible to have a bigger version of the slash which scales correctly in subscripts and superscripts?

Comment: @JohnDorian That's not a problem with the slash; try *any* `\big` delimiter in subscripts and superscripts

Comment: Alright, and do you have any suggestion what to do, if I think the slash for quotient structures should be bigger than default, and I also sometimes have to use it in subscripts?

Comment: @JohnDorian OK, now I *think* to have understood the problem.

Comment: @JohnDorian See edit

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry that my question was not clearly formulated.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have given a better minimal example. I just realised that your answer does not work with the use of `unicode-math` and lualatex. Can it be adapted for this setup?

Comment: @JohnDorian I changed the code in the part that seems to interest you, so to get a solution independent on `unicode-math`.